# Inheritance in Groovy -Base class table lists entries of sub class

Tags: java, inheritance, grails, groovy

I have  class Contract which extends Base class Rule . i have different CRUD for Rule and Contract. my base class has got 6 fields and derived class got 3 specified fields. when i am listing the Rules created, it also displays Contract which is saved in the table. if i am listing rule it should list only Rules. how can i do that? what is the Thing that i need to take care when dealing with groovy inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is logically correct as per the hierarchy you have, as every contract is rule also. IMO, there could be two options :

- Create another subclass of Rule that would only mean Rule not the contract, as you separate CRUD for them too.
- Add a property (may be RuleType Enum) to both Rule and Contract, to differentiate amogst them and then use Rule.findAllByRuleType(RuleType.OnlyRule)

Comment: Thank you Amit... I have did something similar to what you have said... Thanks alot